# Unit Tests in Xamarin's View Model

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms

We're working on a project that has very little business logic.  Essentially, we gather information from the user and call a REST API with that information.  We get back information that we display.

Is there any point in trying to create unit tests for this kind of class?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the importance of this application and this specific functionality. If it is business critical, then most probably it is a good idea to wrap it by unit tests. Even with a very little business logic you may run into exceptional cases, which your application should be ready for:

- No network
- Unreliable network
- Incorrect / malicious user input
- Incorrect server response

Alternatively, it may make sense to replace unit tests by UI tests or to have both. In this case it will be possible to test the `user flow` rather that a very simple bits and bytes.